# Flutter: How to get a specific document in firestore when using Streambuilder<QuerySnapshot>

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout

I'm currently having a problem on my code, where in I'm trying to get a specific data on my database. I want to do is COLLECTION > SPECIFIC DOCUMENT I'M TRYING TO GET > FIELDS (MY ARRAY DATA). As of now I have a code where it does what I'm trying to do but the problem it only gets the first data on my document. Please help.

My code:

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                stream: db.collection('NOTIFICATION').snapshots(),
                builder: (context, snapshot) {
                  if (snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Column (
                        children: snapshot.data.documents.first['Respondent']
                            .map<Widget>((respondent) => buildItem(respondent))
                            .toList());
                  } else {
                    return SizedBox();
                  }
                })
```

My database structure:

[image]

Badly need help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change this:

```
snapshot.data.documents.first['Respondents'];
```

for this:

```
snapshot.data.documents.firstWhere((doc) => doc.documentID == 'id')['Respondents'];
```

---

Handling different cases:

```
var doc = snapshot.data.documents
    .firstWhere((doc) => doc.documentID == 'id', orElse: () => null);
if (doc == null) {
  return Text('Document doesn\'t exist');
} else if (doc['Respondents'] == null) {
  return Text('Document without respondents');
} 
return Column(children: doc['Respondents'].map<Widget>(...));
```

Comment: It appears to be saying Bad state: No element sir @pablo.

Comment: It works sir @pablo, but the problem is if theres no data on the "id" that is used for reference. it shows the infinite loop of "Bad state: No element", How can I fix this sir? I tried to output just a container or a sized box but it doesnt work.

Comment: It still show an infinite loop of "Bad state: No element" sir :(

Comment: should I still wrap it in if(snapshot.hasdata){ }?

Comment: Its working now! Thanks so much sir @pablo. You're the only one that helps me always. Much respect to you.

Comment: Yes, I recommend that you try to understand each line that you code to make it easier to solve these problems.

Comment: Sir @pablo can you take a look at my new post, maybe you know how to fix it. Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Sir @Pablo, I really need your help, maybe you know how to fix my problem on my new post. No one else is answering :(